# RUST: Better (simpler/pritter) way to use enum from struct?

Tags: struct, rust, enums

Maybe it is a little weird question, but is there a better (simpler/prettier) way to use "enum from struct"? Without "option" ? Please.

Below some simple variants of code for: "Struct only", "Enum only" and bloody "Enum from Struct"...
It could be much easier to grab a hint, if "Your advise" could be used on presented code.

[https://play.rust-lang.org/](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7859ca839b19fcf29c0e4aef511e2ad1)

```
fn main() {
//   ----   STRUCT only:
#[derive(Debug)]

struct Ipv4Addr {
    v4: (u8, u8, u8, u8),
}

#[derive(Debug)]

struct Ipv6Addr {
    v6: String,
}

let home = Ipv4Addr { v4: (127, 0, 0, 1) };

let loopback = Ipv6Addr {
    v6: String::from("::1"),
};

println!("\n\tStruct:\n");

println!("home: {:?} , loopback: {:?}", home, loopback);

//   ----   ENUM 1 - only enum:

#[derive(Debug)]

enum IpAddr2 {
    V4(u8, u8, u8, u8),
    V6(String),
}

let home1 = IpAddr2::V4(127, 0, 0, 1);

let loopback1 = IpAddr2::V6(String::from("::1"));

println!("\n\tEnum1:\n");

println!("home1: {:?}, loopback1: {:?}\n", home1, loopback1);

//   ----   ENUM 2 - from Struct:

#[derive(Debug)]

enum IpAddr {
    V4(Ipv4Addr),
    V6(Ipv6Addr),
}

let home2 = IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr { v4: (127, 0, 0, 1) }); // <-- *a little "meh"?

let loopback2 = IpAddr::V6(Ipv6Addr {
    v6: ("::1").to_string(),                            // <-- *?
});

println!("\n\tEnum2:\n");

println!("home2: {:?}, loopback2: {:?}\n", home2, loopback2);}
```

Comment: If the creation syntax is too verbose, the typical approach is to create a constructor, e.g. `impl IpAddr { fn new_v4(v4: (u8, u8, u8, u8)) -> IpAddr { IpAddr::v4(Ipv4Addr { v4 }) }`.

Comment: note that std have a IpAddr already

Comment: @user4815162342 : ? -> [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb08c2c9e53395d8d980f63a680c5e1d)

Comment: @user4815162342 what with -> 'fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Ipv4Addr {
        v4: (u8, u8, u8, u8),
    }
    impl Ipv4Addr {
        fn new_ip4(v4: (u8, u8, u8, u8)) -> Ipv4Addr {
            Ipv4Addr { v4 }
        }
    }
    let ip4 = Ipv4Addr::new_ip4((1, 1, 1, 1));
    println!("{:?}", ip4)
}

Comment: self problem-storing here: 'fn main() {

    #[derive(Debug)]

    struct Ipv4Addr {
        v4: (u8, u8, u8, u8),
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]

    struct Ipv6Addr {
        v6: String,
    }

    impl Ipv4Addr {
        fn aip_4(&self) -> (u8, u8, u8, u8) {
            self.v4
        }
    }

    impl Ipv6Addr {
        fn aip_6(&self) -> &String {
            &self.v6
        }
    }

    let ipv4 = Ipv4Addr { v4: (1, 1, 1, 1) };

    let ipv6 = Ipv6Addr { v6: ("::1".into()) };

    println!("ip4: {:?} , ip6: {:?}", ipv4.aip_4(), ipv6.aip_6());
}
'

Comment: more "this ip" in one place, not sure if written in correct way :/ [link] (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de74a3b11b4b66e460cfcfcc23ba610c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use tuple structs for this? Something like

```
struct Ipv4(u8,u8,u8,u8);
struct Ipv6(String); // isn't ipv6 8*u16?

enum IpAddr {
    V4(Ipv4),
    V6(Ipv6),
}

fn main() {
    let ip4 = IpAddr::V4(Ipv4(192,168,0,1));
    let ip6 = IpAddr::V6(Ipv6("::1".into()));
}
```

Comment: Short and clean. Thank you.  :)